# Regex having @ character on the middle

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation

Trying to create a function in C# to validate if a string is passes these rules

<Optional any character including symbols except @><atleast 1 alphanumeric character>@<atleast 1 alphanumeric character><Optional any character including symbols except @>

Basically make sure that there is an @ symbol in the middle

Passed

```
a@a
1@1
a@1
1@a
11@aa
#!@#1a!#a
1@dasdas2!#
```

Fails

```
1a@!  fails because alphanumeric character should be besided @
!@ada fails because alphanumeric character should be besided @
a@a@b fails because has 2 @
a@    fails no character on the right
@b    fails no character on the left
@     fails no character beside @
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Your description doesn't match your inputs

Comment: @TheGeneral Please elaborate.

Comment: How does this pass `#!@#1a!#a` when you say "*<atleast 1 alphanumeric character>@<atleast 1 alphanumeric character>*" amongst other oddities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```regex
^[^@]?[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+[^@]?$
```

However, as already mentioned in the comments, your last two "passing" inputs don't match your rules -- `#!@#1a!#a` lacks an alphanumeric character before the `@` and has non-alphanumeric characters in positions other than the first and last character. `1@dasdas2!#` has two symbols at the end, but the rules would dictate that the `!` would not be valid, as it's not alphanumeric.

Note that "alphanumeric" can mean different things depending on locale. In the above, I took it literally as A-Z, a-z, and 0-9, but there are many other characters that are "letters" or "numbers" out there. `\w` might be a better substitute, if it's supported by your variant of regex (you didn't specify the variant), but usually, `\w` would also allows an underscore (`_`). This if course isn't "alphanumeric," so you'd need forward-looking assertions to disallow the `_` (which, again, would be variant-specific, since regex is not completely standardized across implementations).

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow dots as symbols

Comment: it doesnt seem to allow symbols 1b2!a3@qad11# this should work.

Comment: Byron, this would allow "." as a symbol for any regex variant I'm aware of. And "1b2!a3@qad11#" doesn't match the rules you stated, since the "!" symbol is in the middle of the first part, not at the start or end of the string. Here's a URL for testing the pattern I wrote above: https://regex101.com/r/O7PlFX/1